# При развертывании проекта на сервере через build выдает ошибку, что делать?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, развертывание

У меня задача развернуть проект на windows server через build.
У себя локально я делаю npm run build и далее получаю build но с ошибками, но как я понимаю они не должны мешать работе app. Вот что я получаю при билде проекта:

```
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

./src/containers/home/TrendingPosts/index.jsx
  Line 11:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getTrending'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'getTrending' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/containers/auth/metamask/index.jsx
  Line 16:11:  'width' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                    no-unused-vars
  Line 51:55:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noopener noreferrer" is a security risk: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener  react/jsx-no-target-blank

./src/components/ordinary/Marquee/index.jsx
  Line 17:24:  Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string
  Line 18:24:  Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string
  Line 19:24:  Unexpected template string expression  no-template-curly-in-string

./src/components/ordinary/user/index.jsx
  Line 1:17:  'useRef' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/containers/image/index.jsx
  Line 25:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getImageData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'getImageData' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/components/simple/post/index.jsx
  Line 28:46:  Unexpected string concatenation of literals  no-useless-concat

./src/App.js
  Line 2:28:  'useState' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/components/Routes.jsx
  Line 2:32:  'Redirect' is defined but never used                                                                         no-unused-vars
  Line 40:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/containers/Tape/index.jsx
  Line 30:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'getImagesHandler' and 'loading'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 34:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getImagesHandler'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/containers/NavBar/index.jsx
  Line 32:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getUserBalance'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/core/hooks/useLikes.js
  Line 35:19:  'res' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                                                                                                                                             no-unused-vars
  Line 67:38:  The ref value 'el.current' will likely have changed by the time this effect cleanup function runs. If this ref points to a node rendered by React, copy 'el.current' to a variable inside the effect, and use that variable in the cleanup function  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 68:8:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handler'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                                                                                                                           react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/containers/editPost/index.jsx
  Line 37:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getPostData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'getPostData' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/components/smart/search/result/index.jsx
  Line 3:16:  'object' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/core/hooks/uploadFiles.js
  Line 43:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'files' and 'uiFiles'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/containers/auth/walletConnect/index.jsx
  Line 48:7:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text

./src/components/ordinary/TopPosts/TopPosts.jsx
  Line 4:10:  'swiperSettings' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/components/simple/RightNav/index.jsx
  Line 4:8:  'Link' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/core/api/likes/index.js
  Line 5:15:  'res' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/core/api/user/index.js
  Line 61:13:  'user' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 72:13:  'res' is assigned a value but never used   no-unused-vars
  Line 81:13:  'res' is assigned a value but never used   no-unused-vars

./src/containers/user/index.jsx
  Line 64:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getUserDataQuery'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/components/ordinary/formPost/index.jsx
  Line 6:8:  'Link' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/components/smart/createPost/index.jsx
  Line 7:8:  'Link' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/components/smart/tape/index.jsx
  Line 7:9:  The 'scrollHandler' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 25) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the 'scrollHandler' definition into its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/containers/home/TopPosts/index.jsx
  Line 9:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getTopPosts'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'getTopPosts' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  456.65 KB  build\static\js\2.06539643.chunk.js
  27.41 KB   build\static\js\main.d8599842.chunk.js
  3.49 KB    build\static\css\main.c9e009c8.chunk.css
  3.33 KB    build\static\css\2.b49f9c43.chunk.css
  1.73 KB    build\static\js\3.f7997a40.chunk.js
  1.17 KB    build\static\js\runtime-main.6d09a018.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at ./public/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:

  bit.ly/CRA-deploy
```

Далее я запускаю проект на сервере через **serve -s build -l 5000**
и получаю извещение, что проект запущен:

[image: Ошибка в консоле]

В чем может быть проблема? До этого такой проблемы не было.

Comment: Вы сделали билд. Откройте index.html из билда в браузере. Сайт нормально отображается?

Comment: Открыл, и я вижу, что картинка которая стояла при загрузке приложения сейчас выглядит в виде иконки, якобы она не загрузилась ( я так понимаю, что я не правильно указал путь ) Хотя локально все работает.

Comment: Я просто не могу понять в чем проблема у Вас и что не получается. Если index.html из билда отображают сайт как надо, то одно дело, а если нет - значит при создании билда проблема и надо смотреть здесь.

Comment: index.html  после билда сайт не тображает, просто черный экран. Я так понимаю, что в билде дело.. Вот, что выводит после билда в консоле
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.
Далее много ошибок. Дело в том, что когда я обычно загружаю на сервер проект и запускаю его там через npm start - все работает. Ошибки в консоле тоже есть, но они не критичны.

Comment: Ну есть какая-то проблема, мешающая билду. Нужно смотреть какие там ошибки. Приложите, отредактировав вопрос или новый создайте

Comment: Создал новый вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1384352/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-syntaxerror-unexpected-toke