# После создания билда с его запуска я получаю ошибку SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, развертывание, build

Задача поставить приложение на сервер.  Начну с того, что если я просто переношу app на сервер и делаю npm start то app запускается и работает нормально.
Если я делаю билд проекта то он создается с ошибками, но без проблем запускается. Вот после того как я сделал билд с его запустил я получаю в консоле вот такую ошибку:
[image: Ошибка при билде]
далее ошибки которые возникают при создании билда:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

./src/containers/home/TrendingPosts/index.jsx
  Line 11:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getTrending'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'getTrending' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/containers/image/index.jsx
  Line 25:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getImageData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'getImageData' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/components/simple/post/index.jsx
  Line 28:46:  Unexpected string concatenation of literals  no-useless-concat

./src/components/Routes.jsx
  Line 2:32:  'Redirect' is defined but never used                                                                         no-unused-vars
  Line 40:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/containers/Tape/index.jsx
  Line 30:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'getImagesHandler' and 'loading'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 34:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getImagesHandler'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/containers/NavBar/index.jsx
  Line 32:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getUserBalance'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/core/hooks/useLikes.js
  Line 35:19:  'res' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                                                                                                                                             no-unused-vars
  Line 67:38:  The ref value 'el.current' will likely have changed by the time this effect cleanup function runs. If this ref points to a node rendered by React, copy 'el.current' to a variable inside the effect, and use that variable in the cleanup function  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 68:8:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handler'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                                                                                                                           react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/containers/editPost/index.jsx
  Line 37:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getPostData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'getPostData' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/components/smart/search/result/index.jsx
  Line 3:16:  'object' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/core/hooks/uploadFiles.js
  Line 43:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'files' and 'uiFiles'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/containers/auth/walletConnect/index.jsx
  Line 48:7:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text

./src/components/ordinary/TopPosts/TopPosts.jsx
  Line 4:10:  'swiperSettings' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/components/simple/RightNav/index.jsx
  Line 4:8:  'Link' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/containers/auth/metamask/index.jsx
  Line 50:13:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noopener noreferrer" is a security risk: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener  react/jsx-no-target-blank

./src/core/api/likes/index.js
  Line 5:15:  'res' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/core/api/user/index.js
  Line 61:13:  'user' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 72:13:  'res' is assigned a value but never used   no-unused-vars
  Line 81:13:  'res' is assigned a value but never used   no-unused-vars

./src/containers/user/index.jsx
  Line 64:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getUserDataQuery'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/components/ordinary/formPost/index.jsx
  Line 6:8:  'Link' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/components/smart/createPost/index.jsx
  Line 7:8:  'Link' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

./src/components/smart/tape/index.jsx
  Line 7:9:  The 'scrollHandler' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 25) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the 'scrollHandler' definition into its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/containers/home/TopPosts/index.jsx
  Line 9:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getTopPosts'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'getTopPosts' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  456.65 KB  build\static\js\2.06539643.chunk.js
  27.42 KB   build\static\js\main.56d9c162.chunk.js
  3.49 KB    build\static\css\main.c9e009c8.chunk.css
  3.33 KB    build\static\css\2.b49f9c43.chunk.css
  1.73 KB    build\static\js\3.f7997a40.chunk.js
  1.17 KB    build\static\js\runtime-main.6d09a018.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at ./public/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:

  bit.ly/CRA-deploy
```

Насколько я понимаю тут нету ничего критичного в этих ошибках. Через npm start все работает и ошибки в консоле так же есть, но проект запускается, а вот при билде получаю вот такой результат. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Иногда бывают ошибки, связанный с транспиляцией. Откати код, до рабочего состояния. И пошагово возвращайся вперёд. Так найдёшь код, который не верно транспилируется. Перепеши его и всё поедет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос. Дело все было в параметре homepage в package.json. Я просто удалил этот параметр и все заработало. Вебпак новенький как то странно работает с параметром homepage, пытаясь в жс засунуть голый хтмл, из за этого и проблема.

Comment: а мне не помогло, хотя все пишут что это помогает, у меня изначально параметра не было и не работает

Answer (score 0):

нажми на ошибку (там где написан номер.chunk.js) - что бы развернуть код, где она происходит и через глобальный поиск попробуй найти это место

Comment: Мне кажется, это нужно перенести в комментарий.

Comment: После того как я нажал на chunk.js, в кладке Sources я получаю билд проекта который идет строкой. В нем  понять что не так невозможно, т.к. все подсвечивается красным.